# Can not send_file with Kohana 3.2

Tags: php, kohana, mime-types, kohana-3.2

For some reason when using

```
$this->response->send_file($file_to_send, $file->hashed_name.'.'.$file->extension);
```

I get errors like this:

```
ErrorException [ Warning ]: mime_content_type() [<a href='function.mime-content-type'>function.mime-content-type</a>]: can only process string or stream arguments
```

SYSPATH/classes/kohana/file.php [ 52 ]

```
47      }
48 
49      if (ini_get('mime_magic.magicfile') AND function_exists('mime_content_type'))
50      {
51          // The mime_content_type function is only useful with a magic file
52          return mime_content_type($filename);
53      }
```

Trace shows that `mime_content_type(arguments)` seems to be `bool FALSE` for some reason.
However I pass to `send_file` normal string full path like `/var/www/dev3/media_files/files/113b778d9751e7d1667b300557b6e8030ba1227e68ef9c4dd093a4cd79691f9d.png`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked Kohana system files and it turned out that I can pass mime_type manualy as an option, so this works perfectly:

```
$this->response->send_file($file_to_send, $file->name.'.'.$file->extension, array('mime_type' => File::mime_by_ext($file->extension)));
```

However, standard `$this->response->send_file($file_to_send)` does not work for me.